# Example of group of order $216$ with a property

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In the  [slides](http://faculty.evansville.edu/rm43/publications/stand05slides.pdf) on commutators in groups, the author states one fact (p.10-11), whose reference is not mentioned there.

> There is a group of order $216$ in which derived subgroup is non-abelian of order $24$ and the set of commutators is not a subgroup.

I wanted to see the structure of such group(s). Can anyone help to get structure (presentation) of such group. Also, is such group of order $216$ unique?

Comment: See the actual [article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/53d4/a956b11fa4a840bbac8260408cbb1c83106a.pdf) (Kappe and Morse, *On commutators in groups*. Groups St. Andrews 2005, Vol. 2, pp. 531-558. LMS Lecture Notes Ser., 340, CUP, 2007) Example 4.3, 4.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are appear to be three groups with those properties, namely $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(216,i)$, with $i=39,41,42$.

They have very similar structures with $[G,G] \cong Q_8 \times C_3$, $G/[G,G] \cong C_3 \times C_3$. They all have $22$ commutators.

They all have nonabelian Sylow $3$-subgroups of order $27$, of exponent 3 in one case and exponent 9 for the other 2. This was just a quick calculation and I have not found any structural difference between those last two groups.